# Drawing a concave polygon in OpenGL(error)

Tags: c, opengl, tessellation

I am trying to draw an L shaped polygon using OpenGL in C. According to me this code should do it but instead it doesn't give me the expected result. The shape I am trying to draw is something similar to below. The point where the error occurs is at point 2 in function polygon1.

Is there some mistake that I seem to be making here or is it a bug in OpenGL. The pic shown below is the error-red output and the diagram drawn below that, is the expected output from the code.

[image]

```
    ----
    |  |
    |  |
  ---  |
  |    |
  ------
```

---

```
void polygon1(float x,float y)
{
  glColor3f(0,1,0);
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glVertex2f(x,y);
  glVertex2f(x,y+25);
  glVertex2f(x+25,y+25);
  glVertex2f(x+25,y+75);
  glVertex2f(x+50,y+75);
  glVertex2f(x+50,y);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
}

void mydisplay()
{
  polygon1(200.0,25.0);
}

void main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
  glutInitWindowPosition(540,320);
  glutCreateWindow("my first attempt");
  glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0,0.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
  glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
  gluOrtho2D(0.0,400.0,0.0,400.0);
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Please post the exact error message.

Comment: I have uploaded an image of the erred output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Drew Hall pointed out in a previous answer, GL_POLYGON cannot draw concave polygons. You can draw this shape with single triangle fan, though. Try this:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glVertex2f(x+25,y+25);
glVertex2f(x,y+25);
glVertex2f(x,y);
glVertex2f(x+50,y);
glVertex2f(x+50,y+75);
glVertex2f(x+25,y+75);
glEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne!. That made everything easy.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL only renders convex polygons properly.  Your "L" needs to be broken into a triangle strip.  You can do this manually or via GLU tesselators (I'm assuming GLU is an option for you as you're rendering in immediate mode anyways).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying to Google and learn how it can be done using GLU tesselators. If you have any link, book name to look into please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, OpenGL can't do this on its own (unless you store the triangles beforehand)

OpenGL doesn't provide a tessellator, but GLU does, as has been mentioned.

If libGLU isnt an option there are a few tessellators out there - libGDX has quite a simple implementation *(in Java - but easy to port)*.

- http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/EarClippingTriangulator.html

*Blender has a C port of this code with optimizations (using 2D kd-tree)*

- https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/polyfill2d.c